# Proper use of induction vessels

Tags: equipment

I accidentally bought a set of induction vessels. Currently I have a gas cooking range. Can induction vessels be used on a regular gas stove or electric stove?

Comment: I've personally never heard of cookware that worked w/ induction that didn't work with gas or resistive electric.  Usually the problem is the other way around.

Comment: What type did you buy?

Answer (score 1):

Induction cookware is only that which has enough steel or iron in it to have a magnet stick to it.  As was mentioned in the comment, it is usually the other way around.  Stainless steel and cast iron are great for cooking on most any type stove top... Or a grill or a campfire!  They are the epitome of versatility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the induction vessels will work with the gas. The only problem I believe is the tough stains that remains in the vessel is we constantly use them in high heat in gas.